# SQL - Increment after 5 rows ordered by date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, auto-increment

I created a table which contains a column called `date`. Now I need to find a way to order the result set and add a new `column` which increments only after 5 ordered date.

For example

```
------------------------
| Date        | Number |
------------------------
| 01/jan/2020 | 1      |
| 02/jan/2020 | 1      |
| 05/jan/2020 | 1      |
| 07/jan/2020 | 1      |
| 10/jan/2020 | 1      |
| 11/jan/2020 | 2      |
| 11/jan/2020 | 2      |
| 12/jan/2020 | 2      |
------------------------
```

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `date` column, is this a string?

Comment: Can duplicate dates be assigned different numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, (4 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `date`)) MOD 5 `number`
FROM sourcetable
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be storing dates as strings. You should definitely fix that design flaw.

To order the record, you need to conert the strings to dates. For this, you can use `str_to_date()`. You can compute the numbers using `row_number()` and simple arithmetics:

```
select
    date,
    1 + floor((row_number() over(order by str_to_date(date, '%d/%b/%Y')) - 1) / 5) rn
from mytable
order by str_to_date(date, '%d/%b/%Y')
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a variable:

```
select date, 1 + floor((@rn := @rn + 1) / 5) rn
from (
    select date, str_to_date(date, '%d/%b/%Y') real_date
    from mytable
    order by real_date
) t
cross join (select @rn := -1) x
```